How to fix python error "OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context" on windows 10?
On a windows 10 system I am trying to listen to a multicast sender given an IP address and a port. It works without any problems on Ubuntu, but on windows I get the error
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

The error appears in a part where I try to bind a socket:
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((group, port))

I see the IP address of group and the port visible on wireshark.
How to fix that error ideally without rebooting the laptop?

I tried to restart the network adaptor using netsh but that did not help.
I tried to run the python script as admin but that did not help
Rebooting the laptop also did not help
I added the path to the python executable I use from a virtualenv to the list of allowed apps through the firewall, but - you might have guessed it - that also did not help


This error occurs when trying to bind to the multicast group's IP address.
Binding to a local interface(s) instead will get rid of the error and allow receipt of multicast packets.
sock.bind(('', port))


It seems this problem cannot be solved. You have to use a different OS.
